# Init a ViewController with a value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, uiviewcontroller

I just created a new view controller for my iphone app.

The view controller is triggered when user tap down a button.
The designated initializer for view controller is the default `(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil`.

I would an initializer like `initWithID:(NSInteger)id` but how to call the designated initializer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't like the portability provided by constructing a view controller using

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;
```

So I often only use it internally anyway but it may look something like this

```
- (id)initWithId:(NSString *)identification
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"nibName" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        _identification = identification;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Note you shouldn't use `id` as a name as it is a type and therefore is confusing

If view controller `A` is constructing view controller `B` I like to think that if my code is loosely coupled enough then `B` should have a better idea than `A` as to what nib `B` should load.

Answer (score 1):

Make a method in the .h file called:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil ID:(NSInteger)idNumber;
```

And then in the .m file, implement the method as:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil ID:(NSInteger)idNumber; {
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if(self != nil){
    // use the idNumber here!
  }
  return self;
}
```

**Edit:** I used `id` for the `NSInteger` as he used it in his question. I changed it to `idNumber` now, as people didn't seems to like it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I downvoted it because of some flaws in the code (id is not a valid parameter name) and because Paul.s 's answer is better.

Comment: I fixed that variable's parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

.h file

```
-(id)initWithID:(NSInteger)id;
```

.m file

```
-(id)initWithID:(NSInteger)id{

   self = [super initWithNibName:@"nib name" bundle:nil];
   if(self){
       //do what you want with the id
   }

   return self;
}
```

Comment: @WTP: Cyprian appears to have edited his answer to include that change.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is to use a **property** (at least that is how it is done in most of Apple's sample code).

In .h:

```
@interface MyViewController {
    NSInteger viewID;
}

@property (assign) NSInteger viewID;
@end
```

In .m:

```
@synthesize viewID;
```

In the View Controller that pushes it:

```
MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
controller.viewID = integerValue;
// and push the view controller
```

BTW, if the nib name is the same as the class name, just alloc-init will have the same effect.